# Tableau tool vs apache Zeppelin

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, tableau-api, apache-zeppelin

I am using apache Zeppelin for sometime now. I want to decide on a good tool for reporting using Spark/Scala. Please compare Zeppelin and Tableau.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Syncfusion Dashboard Designer, provides support to design the dashboard against the BigData through SparkSQL Or Hive connection. Refer,

https://help.syncfusion.com/dashboard-platform/dashboard-designer/connecting-to-data/connecting-to-data#connecting-to-spark-sql-data

https://help.syncfusion.com/dashboard-platform/dashboard-designer/connecting-to-data/connecting-to-data#connecting-to-hive-data